# how to fix "TypeError: translate () got an unexpected keyword argument 'dest'"

Tags: python, bots, telegram, translation, google-translate

I'm creating a telegram bot that translates the messages put in input. When I run the code I get the following error "TypeError: translate () got an unexpected keyword argument 'dest'". Can anyone help me to correct the error? Thank you

This is the script:

```
import telebot

from google_trans_new import google_translator
translator = google_translator()

API_TOKEN = '************************************'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


# Handle '/start' and '/help'
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, """\
Ciao, sono un bot.
Sono stato creato da Riccardo.\
""")

def traduz(parola):

    translations = translator.translate(parola, dest='ko')
    for translation in translations:
       return(translation.origin, ' -> ', translation.text)


# Handle all other messages with content_type 'text' (content_types defaults to ['text'])
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
        bot.reply_to(message, traduz(message.text))


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: I searched around and found [`google_trans_new` docs](https://pypi.org/project/google-trans-new/) on pypi. It seems like you are trying to use its translator like the `googlerans` api, but they are different. It could be `translator.translate(parola, lang_tgt='ko')`. But you may need to check their docs.

Comment: @tdelaney I tried to change it but nothing goes yet. Can you tell me if there is an error when it takes the text to be translated as input?

This is now the new part:

`def traduz(parola):
    translate_text = translator.translate(parola, lang_tgt='en')
    return(translate_text)`

Comment: I don't have the software installed so am just making suggestions from the API definition. Are you getting another error now? What is it?

Comment: @tdelaney When I send him a message to be translated by telegram he tells me this:
`google_trans_new.google_trans_new.google_new_transError: Failed to connect. Probable cause: timeout`
Also, do you know where it is possible to learn how to program a bot with python?